# Unable to load Maven meta-data error while executing Jenkins project

Tags: jenkins, gradle, maven-metadata

While running my existing Jenkins Project I am running into the below issue as soon as I start it -

[Click to view the error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GBoWl.jpg)

I tried hitting the URL for Maven Meta Data (as in the screen shot) manually to check 401 issue but I am able to download the meta data file through browser. artifact.unx is an internal site. I have re-checked my access to the site as well and it works fine. Also, this has been a recent issue and Jenkins project executed just fine some days back.

Any lead here would be useful.

Comment: Tried executing the test using command line with the below command and I am able to run the tests -                                                                                       C:\forecast\Jenkins\workspace\BVTDeployment\gradlew.bat clean integrationtest -DHTTP_HOST=%host% -D###_USER=%Username% -D###_PASS=%Password% -DintegrationTest.single=BVTDeployment                 but when I do it through Jenkins I am still getting the same error as mentioned in the original question.

Answer (score 0):

Most likely your repository requires authentication and something changed in the setup of it, a proxy or the machine running Jenkins jobs that make it no longer authorised.

Gradle supports multiple schemes of authentication for repositories. Have a look at [the documentation](https://docs.gradle.org/5.4.1/userguide/repository_types.html#sub:supported_transport_protocols).